# Trigger with INSERTED WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to update two columns after an initial update of another column.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName 
ON tableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPDATE (columnName)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tableName
        SET dateColumn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            userColumn = SUSER_NAME
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE tableName.PrimaryID = INSERTED.PrimaryID
    END
END
```

The error I am getting:

> Invalid column name 'SUSER_NAME'.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try `SUSER_SNAME()`.

Comment: WOW, that worked...wth...if you add it as an answer ill gladly accept it @DanGuzman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SUSER_SNAME` function requires parenthesis:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET dateColumn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    userColumn = SUSER_NAME()
FROM INSERTED
WHERE tableName.PrimaryID = INSERTED.PrimaryID;
```